# Use Dictionary by variable name

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, collections

I have several dictionary types assigned like this

```
Public aryAAA As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Dictionary(Of String, String))
Public aryBBB As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Dictionary(Of String, String))
Public aryCCC As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
Public aryDDD As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
```

In a database I stored the names of `aryAAA`, `aryBBB`, `aryCCC`, and `aryDDD`. In my program if I read a database record and it has `aryCCC` returned, I then want to be able to use that dictionary.

I was thinking that I would have to assign an object to the `aryCCC` by iterating through the `system.collecton.generic.dictionary` and then use that object to retrieve the data stored. Not sure how I would do this or if there is a better way to use the dictionary by a variable returned name?

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a `Select` or `If/Else` for this. We could do a little better within the type system if all the dictionaries held the same type of object, but since there are differences this is the best we can do:

```
If dbValue = "aryCCC" Then
    'Do stuff with aryCCC
Else If dbValue = "aryAAA" Then
     'Do stuff with aryAAA

   'etc
End If
```

Even reflection won't help much here, since those variables aren't members and we'd still have the different types to deal with.

Ultimately, you have a **run-time** value from the database you want to match up to **compile-time** variable names, and that never goes well.

Comment: I was leaning toward having to do this. I was hoping there was a way to iterate through the system collection and point to a selected entry. If we had the same types defined, would there be a better way to do this? If I just had aryCCC and aryDDD and other like that would we take a different approach.

Comment: I went with the Select Case approach and it worked fine. A little more code to maintain if I add additional variables, but still workable. Thanks for the help.